# How to find the starting position of the last word from the string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

What will be the Postgres equivalent for the below code from Oracle.

```
Select instr('abc de fgh',' ', -1) from dual;
```

returns: `7`

Original code: `substr(country, instr(country,' ', -1)+1);`

I want to create the same logic in Postgres but position & reverse function didn't work

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You apparently want the last element from the string where elements are delimited by a space character.

If you are using Postgres 14, you can use:

```
split_part('abc de fgh', ' ', -1);
```

which returns `fgh`

Or with a column reference: `split_part(country, ' ', -1)`

In earlier versions, `split_part()` doesn't allow negative offsets, so you would need something different:

```
(string_to_array('abc de fgh', ' '))[cardinality(string_to_array('abc de fgh', ' '))]
```

It's a bit shorter with a column reference:

```
(string_to_array(country, ' '))[cardinality(string_to_array(country, ' '))]
```

This first converts the string into an array, then picks the last element of the array (which in turn is determined using the `cardinality()` function that returns the length of the array)

Comment: The code in my answer does the same as `substr(country, instr(country,' ', -1)+1)`

Comment: Can you please tell what will be the code for this from Oracle.
substr(country, 1, instr(country,' ', -1)-1)  

And can you please elaborate how to use this cardinality function.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention `REVERSE`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(value, POSITION(' ' in REVERSE(value)) - 1) AS country,
       LENGTH(value) - POSITION(' ' in REVERSE(value)) + 1 AS pos
FROM   (SELECT 'abc de fgh' AS value) v;
```

Which outputs:

> | country | pos |
> | --- | --- |
> | fgh | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8912b18000a340c0b421caca72af1b5)*