# How to extract substring excluding only the last word of string in Postgressql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, substring

What will be the Postgres equivalent code for below code from Oracle:

```sql
trim(substr(country, 1, instr(country,' ', -1)-1));
```

Can anyone help me in how to extract the whole part of string excluding the last word from string, which is separated using space.
eg.

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| NEW YORK 5654 | NEW YORK |
| ST LOUIS PARK, MN 55426-9999 | ST LOUIS PARK, MN |

Comment: Is this the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926548/how-to-find-the-starting-position-of-the-last-word-from-the-string-in-postgresql) to the question?

Comment: @AntonGrig Although they are similar, they are not the same. That question is asking for the position of the last word (and possibly the text of last word) and this question is asking for the substring excluding the last word.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT address,
       LEFT(
         address,
         LENGTH(address) - POSITION(' ' in REVERSE(address))
       ) AS short_address
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (address) AS
SELECT 'NEW YORK 5654' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ST LOUIS PARK, MN 55426-9999'
```

Outputs:

> | address | short_address |
> | --- | --- |
> | NEW YORK 5654 | NEW YORK |
> | ST LOUIS PARK, MN 55426-9999 | ST LOUIS PARK, MN |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ec53b367a6854755d9863847e9471abd)*